# Web Browser Development

Tags: html, css, browser, language-agnostic, standards

If one were to build a new Web Browser, from scratch; Which documents would they need in order to follow Standards?

---

Would they just use the W3C website to obtain information on how HTML and CSS should be parsed?

I apologize if this is too broad of a question, or if I am not providing enough information, but I'm not quite sure how exactly I should ask this type of question.

Comment: welcome to a world of pain

Comment: One might also consider the developments of the [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/).

Comment: @JTS-V Can you write a blog while developing. I'd be highly interested in your experiences.

Comment: Thank you @Sirko, I remember coming across the WHATWG website a while ago. I will add this to my list.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - that's a great idea.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - I am setting up the blog now. The address is: http://jts-v.posterous.com/

Comment: @JTS-V and I subscribed to your feed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building your own web browser is one thing; building a web browser along with a [rendering/layout engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine) from scratch is another.

Rendering engines are what "execute" the HTML/CSS/Scripting code and change it to render-able content. For instance, Mozilla Firefox uses the **[Gecko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29)** engine, while Chrome and Safari use **[WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)**. Writing a decent engine isn't simple -- there are many standards to follow. There are open-source engines (like Gecko), so you don't have to write your own. But in any case, there are 2 main standards to follow:

- [The W3C Standards](http://www.w3.org/standards/)
- [The IETF RFC Drafts](http://www.ietf.org/rfc.html)

Good luck, and I hope that helped you!

Comment: Thank you, @Abody97. Much appreciated. I'm also surprised this question hasn't been flooded with "Don't re-invent the wheel"-type answers/comments.

Comment: I would add the specs for JavaScript/DOM if it's not already included in the above. Designing a browser from the ground up with the DOM in mind is essential; I've seen way too many "new browser" projects die because they first did their own thing for how to represent parsed HTML, then tried to tack on JS (and thus the DOM) as an after-thought...